# how do re-size a HTML <object> tag when the content in it is dynamic

Tags: html, object, resize

I have some jQuery and HTML that renders an OBJECT tag with a default html page then repopulates the OBJECT on a button click when the new page  ,which is dynamic, is done rendering I'd like to resize the object to be 100% the size of the rendered page is that possible ?

code following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sq').click(function() {
     var actualYear = $('#ay').val() ;
     var actualTerm = $('#tc').val();
     if (actualTerm == '01')
     {
      actualYear = Number($('#ay').val()) + 1;
     }
     var actualTC = actualYear + actualTerm;                                                               + $('#smcSel').val() +  "&ccc=" + $('#cccSel').val()  + "&ac=" + $('#acSel').val() + "&cs=" + $('#csSel').val() + "&cl=" + $('#clSel').val() + "&smd=" + $('#smdSel').val() + "&sm=" + $('#smSel').val()  + "&sl=" + $('#slSel').val()  + "&ib=" + $('#IBID').val() + "&sb=" + $('#SBID').val() + "&ay=" + $('#ay').val() + "&tc=" + $('#ay').val()  + $('#tc').val() + "&tca="+ actualTC + "&mes=" + $('#mes').val()  + "&pr=" + $('#pr').val()  + "&sr=" + $('#sr').val() + "&tr=" + $('#tr').val() + "&col=" + $('#col').val()  + "&mc=";
     var urlis = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/SASStoredProcess/do?_action=execute,nobanner,newwindow&_program=%2FTABBS%2FuQuery%2Ftbir11052&smc=" + $('#smcSel').val() +  "&ccc=" + $('#cccSel').val()  + "&ac=" + $('#acSel').val() + "&cs=" + $('#csSel').val() + "&cl=" + $('#clSel').val() + "&smd=" + $('#smdSel').val() + "&sm=" + $('#smSel').val()  + "&sl=" + $('#slSel').val()  + "&ib=" + $('#IBID').val() + "&sb=" + $('#SBID').val() + "&ay=" + $('#ay').val() + "&tc=" + $('#ay').val()  + $('#tc').val() + "&tca="+ actualTC + "&mes=" + $('#mes').val()  + "&pr=" + $('#pr').val()  + "&sr=" + $('#sr').val() + "&tr=" + $('#tr').val() + "&col=" + $('#col').val()  + "&mc=";


        document.getElementById("contentarea").setAttribute('data', urlis);
    });
});




<div id="result">
<object type="text/html" data="./contentarea.html" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;" id=contentarea></object>

</div>
```

Comment: try to add this style ((style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;")) to (<div id="result">)

Comment: Hey Thanks! yes that did the trick!

Comment: Please vote to the answer

Comment: how do I mark a comment as the answer i dont see button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style `style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"` to `<div id="result">`.

Answer (score 0):

In few browsers, % won't support. So better to specify with pixels (height: 500px; width: 900px;)